# How to log in web project ? best practice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I'm trying to do my first web project using tomcat, jsp, servlets and log4j.  Now i have one logger in AbstractRepository that is initialized like:

```
private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractRepository.class);
```

The question is how to log in subclasses (user repositories, subject repositories etc). Is it better each subclass to have a logger or create getter in AbstractRepository and use only this logger ?

[image: repository hierarchy]

PS help me with the question title

Comment: my answer will be "it depends", but i think it will be better if you have separate logger for each implementation, if you do like that, it will be easier for you to find relevant logs

Comment: @user902383 would you explain in which situations it is preferable to have one logger ?

Comment: maybe not preferable, but sometimes you might not need another logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the Loggers private and create new Loggers for every subclass. If you do that, you can configure the level for every Logger on its own:

```
<logger name="ua.nure.[...etc..].AbstractRepository" level="INFO" />
<logger name="ua.nure.[...etc..].SubjectRepository" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="ua.nure.[...etc..].UserRepository" level="WARN" />
```

If you are free to choose a logging framework, use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). That is a logging facade that will collect the loggings from all [legacy frameworks](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and route it to the framework of your choice, i.e. log4j or logback. I would suggest you to use Logback as the logging implementation, because its already based on SLF4J, modern and fast and it is confiured as easy as Log4J.

**Update**

To get it working you first need to include these Jars into your classpath (through Maven or "lib"-directroy):

1. [slf4j-api.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10)
2. [jcl-over-slf4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j) (redirects Apache Commons Logging to SLF4J)
3. [log4j-over-slf4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j) (redirects Log4J to SLF4J)
4. [jul-to-slf4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j) (redirects Java Util Logging to SLF4J, see [HandlerBridge info](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j))
5. [logback-classic.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic) (redirects from SLF4J to Logback Logging)
6. [logback-core.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core)

Put a file called "logback.xml" in "src/java/resources" (Maven) or in the default package of your classpath ("src") and add some [content](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#syntax), i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="false" scanPeriod="10 seconds">

<!-- This appender prints to stdout: -->
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <Target>System.out</Target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%p %d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%c] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Log levels for specific packages or classes: -->

<logger name="my.company.projectname.package" level="INFO" />

<logger name="ua.nure" level="INFO" />

// add more here ...

<!-- Log levels for all packages and classes can be controlled here: -->
<root level="INFO">
    <!-- add more appenders (rolling file, email, ...) here: -->
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

For example set the root logger to "warn" and your project specific logger to "info". That will show the most logs from your project, but only warnings and errors from other libraries.

In your classes create loggers this way:

```
//default
private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
//static
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
//in a serializable
private transient final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Comment: thanks for your post. would you explain in which file should i include peace of code that you suggest ?

Comment: also would you help me to understand is it safe to use one DataSource object in AbstractRepository and get from him in the way: `protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException { return ds.getConnection(); }`
should put synchronizedon it ? or better to each repository have own DataSource ?

Comment: You should create a new question for that. Have a look at connection pooling like c3po or dbcp. These will handle opening and closing connections for you. Use one pool for all your daos.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/), It use `log.properties` file to set the format and build your logs. Only one global logger which is used by the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `log4j.properties` file in src folder, witch is configured for log message output.Now as you want to know, we need to create separate Logger object for each class.

1. `private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SubjectRepository.class);`
2. `private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserRepository.class);`